How to prevent double processing of a react hook?
I have the following hook which has a useEffect block which I would like to execute as a singlton, I want it to import a public key parse the key and make it available throughout the react app.
Unfortunately this process gets performed N times that the hook is referenced.
I tried de-bouncing the method, but it seems like without using a global variable it's not possible.
I know this might be better suited to a global state management, but I wanted to try it with hooks, as I was inspired by Apollo's useQuery hooks which seem to perform graphql queries as singleton operations and reference an internal cache.
export const usePublicKey = () => {
  const [publicKey, setPublicKey] = useState()
  const fetched = useRef(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchKey = async () => {
      const keys = await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(
        {
            name: 'RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5',
            modulusLength: 2048,
            publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
            hash: 'SHA-256',
        },
        true,
        ['sign', 'verify']
      )
      const _publicKey = await window.crypto.subtle.exportKey('jwk', k.publicKey)
      setPublicKey(_publicKey )
    }
    if(!fetched.current) { // this evaluates true for N times the hook is loaded
      fetched.current = true // this doesn't seem to take effect as part of React Lifecycle
      fetchKey()
    }
  },[])

  return {
    publicKey
  }
}


Looks like the only solution is to useContext for these hooks in order to save state across multiple components and mounts.

^^^ Sure, since React hooks don't magically share state if you want only a single state and handlers then move these into a Context Provider and update usePublicKey to return the context value via the useContext hook. This is a common solution. This way each usePublicKey hook references the single state instead of each "instance"'s local state.
